# Slither-Yajilink: A match made in Hades

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

This is a Slitherlink-Yajilin hybrid. Shade some cells in the grid and draw one non-crossing, non-branching line connecting centres of cells horizontally and vertically, so that the final configuration satisfies the rules of both puzzle types.

Rules of Slitherlink:

- Blue numbers are Slitherlink clues. Each clue indicates how many of the four possible line segments surrounding the number are used for the loop.

Rules of Yajilin:

- Black numbers with grey background are Yajilin clues. The clue indicates how many shaded cells are in the direction of the arrow.
- Two shaded cells cannot share an edge, but they can touch at a corner. Shaded cells can touch clue cells.
- The loop must visit every empty cell in the grid (i.e. every cell that's not shaded and not a clue).

[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2c6tx6mf)

[image: Empty Slither-Yajilink grid]

Comment: Thank you for the puzzle, that was quite fun! I don't know what the convention is here, in terms of what counts as an 'answer', since the solution is already posted.

Comment: @GlennWillen Glad to hear it! We don't generally add a new answer unless it has something significant to add to the existing ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is here. Nice puzzle!

> [image]

Intermediate steps:

> [image] [image] [image] [image]